# Delete older data from MySQL database using Python

Tags: python, mysql

I want to delete records older than 7 days automatically, but it doesn't work. Message is showing that older data is deleted, but actually it did not delete the data.

My code is:

```
try:
    db= MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","","testDB")
    cursor=db.cursor()
    sql="DELETE FROM CALLRECORD WHERE DATE< DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)"
    try:
        cursor.execute(sql)
        db.commit()
        print "Deleted Older Data from database"

    except:
        db.rollback()
        print "Cann't delete older data"
    db.close()

except:
    print "localserver not connected"
```

Comment: Hey @Akash Nil did you try changing the operator? Did it work?

Comment: sorry for the delay     <    did not work @ misa lazovic

Comment: as my stored date format in callrecord is dd/mm/yy so I tried   sql="DELETE FROM CALLRECORD WHERE DATE< GET_FORMAT( DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY),'EUR')"  but it shows error

Answer (score 2):

I think you've made a mistake in your query, you are deleting records which inserted in last 7 days. Use below query instead of yours:

```
DELETE FROM CALLRECORD
WHERE DATE < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Comment: my stored date format is dd/mm/yy  when i am using your code it deleting current record. i am using linux for database. i tested WHERE DATE < DATE_SUB(NOW(date +'%d-%m-%y'), INTERVAL 7 DAY) but the result is same. if i am using > sign it did not delete data

Comment: Try UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY))

Comment: in my database data coming every minutes your code deleted all the record

Comment: date entered my callrecord by python command date=datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%y"). then this date related information will stored into callrecord after that it will delete older data suppose stored date is 21/01/16. and it will delete all the record before 14/01/16.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `>` instead of `<`, so you're deleting new records instead of old ones. You need to delete records with date LESS (not greater) than the date that was seven days ago.